# How to filter a list based on a common property (only then to find the min value)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, .net-core, ienumerable

**Problem description:**

I have a scenario of List of `Manufacturers` each contain a `Id`, `CapacityCode`, `Price`. I want to find the cheapest price, but only for items that all of the manufacturers has the same `CapacityCode` in common.

Or

```
public class Manufacturer
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string CapacityCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

**My goal:**

To filter the list by items that has the same capacities codes in common, and then find the min price.

For Example:

```
{
    "Manufacturers": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "CapacityCode": "Foo",
        "Price": 15
    },
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "CapacityCode": "Boo", // Manufacture 2 has no "Boo" so it should be filtered
        "Price": 10
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "CapacityCode": "Foo",
        "Price": 30
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "CapacityCode": "Zoo", // Manufacture 1 has no "Zoo" so it should be filtered
        "Price": 20
    }
}
```

Output for the filtered list should be:

```
{
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "CapacityCode": "Foo",
        "Price": 15
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "CapacityCode": "Foo",
        "Price": 30
    }
}
```

So the min price should be 15.

**I tried (And it worked):**

```
var groups = source.Manufacturers
    .GroupBy(m => m.CapacityCode)
    .ToList();

var max = groups.Max(g => g.Count());
var filtered = new List<Manufacturer>();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    if (group.Count() != max)
        continue;

    filtered.AddRange(group);
}

decimal minPrice = filtered.Min(m => m.Price);
```

**My Question:**

How to achieve the same result in terms of performance and readability?

Comment: So firstly you want the list of Manufacturer with common CapacityCode and then sort them by price right?

Comment: Those properties are all private - how are you setting/grouping/filtering on them? Also, if you group by the `CapacityCode` once, why are you grouping by it a second time? Please show the actual code, especially the part that isn't working.

Comment: @mihir exactly this my goal

Comment: So in case the following item was also included in the list: `{"Id": 3, "CapacityCode": "MEDIUM", "Price": 10}`, no result could be obtained because there would be no `CapacityCode` common to all manufacturers. Correct?

Comment: Hey @RufusL, see the updated question... I omitted the public keyword by purpose for the question to be less verbal, and i added the code instead of the description

Comment: Hey @TheodorZoulias, your item is exactly like my Boo item, so yes it is correct

Comment: Have you checked if the accepted answer returns the correct result (which is no result) in the scenario where there is no `CapacityCode` common to all manufacturers?

Comment: Right, Have not thought about this use case... I'll check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the manufacturers by `CapacityCode` with [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netcore-3.1), get the max count with [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1), filter groups with the max count with [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1), flatten the groups into `IEnumerable<Manufacturer>` with [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1), and sort the prices with [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1).

```
var manufacturers = new List<Manufacturer> {
    new Manufacturer
    {
        Id = 1,
        CapacityCode = "Foo",
        Price = 15
    },
    new Manufacturer
    {
        Id = 1,
        CapacityCode = "Boo",
        Price = 10
    },
    new Manufacturer
    {
        Id = 2,
        CapacityCode = "Foo",
        Price = 30
    } 
    new Manufacturer
    {
        Id = 2,
        CapacityCode = "Zoo",
        Price = 20
    },
};

var groups = manufacturers.ToLookup(manufacturer => manufacturer.CapacityCode);

var maxCount = groups.Max(group => group.Count());

var result = groups
    .Where(group => group.Count() == maxCount)
    .SelectMany(group => group)
    .OrderBy(manufacturer => manufacturer.Price)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC your question, there is no need to group the `Manufacturer` list twice. You can group it by `CapacityCode` and find the max count. Then filter the groups by max count and flatten items using `SelectMany`, order them by `Price` and finally get the minimal price, if it's needed

```cs
var groups = manufacturers
    .GroupBy(m => m.CapacityCode)
    .ToList();

var count = groups.Max(g => g.Count());

var result = groups
    .Where(g => g.Count() == count)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .OrderBy(m => m.Price)
    .ToList();

var minPrice = result.FirstOrDefault()?.Price ?? 0;
```

Comment: Should you use .OrderByDescending(m => m.Price) instead of OrderBy(m => m.Price) otherwise the most expensive is returned first?

Comment: @Damian70 nope, the cheapest price is first

Comment: I didn't see your answer. This is similar to what I did. I think this is what the OP is after.